# Angular promise DataError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I have a service in angular 9 project with this methods :

```
  ....
  private importECDHPublicKey(publicKey) {
    const algorithm = {
      name: 'ECDH',
      namedCurve: 'P-256',
    };
    const pk = new TextEncoder().encode(atob(publicKey));
    return crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', pk, algorithm, false, ['deriveKey', 'deriveBits']);
  }


  private driveECDHPublicKey(publicKey) {
    const algorithm = {
      name: 'ECDH',
      public: publicKey,
    };
    const derivedKeyType = {
      name: 'AES-CBC',
      length: 256,
    };
    return crypto.subtle.deriveKey(algorithm, this.ecdhPrivateKey, derivedKeyType, false, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
  }

  public generateSharedSecretKey(publicKey) {
    this.sharedSecret = this.importECDHPublicKey(publicKey)
      .then(e => this.driveECDHPublicKey(e))
      .then(e => this.deriveECDHSecretKey(this.ecdhPrivateKey, e));
  }
  ....
```

and i used generateSharedSecretKey method in my websocket connection :

```
 this.ws
  .pipe(retryWhen(e => e.pipe(delay(1000))))
  .pipe(e => e.pipe(delay(1000)))
  .subscribe(
    msg => myService.generateSharedSecretKey(msg),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Completed')
  );
```

I have this error when receive [server publicKey] :

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): DataError: Data provided to an
>   operation does not meet requirements"

I can not understand how can fix this problem .
What part of my code has problem ?

**UPDATE:**
Browser debug :      [image]

Comment: Could you debug and show us where the error occurs? Is it a web-request, or in any of the callback-functions?

Comment: @Nikolaus Post updated , this is only debuging information .

Comment: Look in core.js line 5828. If you don’t know the problem, mark the line in your question.